# Comparing csv column name with csv header array

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I am sorry I am editing my question. My real issue is to figure out how to perform a comparison between the $csv_Column_name of fillMapArray function with the value which is stored in the $Csv_header_array in the readRow function. This issue is related to the two csv one table problem since the maps table which stores the csv column name has two csv files loaded into it.

```
public $table;
public $filename;
public $insert_chunk_size = 500;
public $csv_delimiter = ',';
public $offset_rows = 1;
// Array to store Database column names
public $mapping = [];
public function setTableName($tablename)
{
    $this->table = $tablename;
}
public function setFileName($filename)
{
    $this->filename = $filename;
}
public function setColumnMapping()
{
    //Retrieve the column names of the table
    // and store them in the array
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($this->table);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < (sizeof($columns) - 1)) {
        array_push($this->mapping, $columns[$i+1]);
        $i++;
    }
}
public function openCSV($filename)
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        Log::error("CSV insert failed" . $filename . "does not exist or is not readable");
    }
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
    return $handle;
}
public function seedFromCSV($filename, $deliminator = ',')
{
    $handle = $this->openCSV($filename);
    // CSV doesn't exist or couldn't be read from.
    if ( $handle === FALSE )
        return [];
    $header = NULL;
    $row_count = 0;
    $data = [];
    // Array to store CSV Header column names
    $Csv_header_array = [];
    $mapping = $this->mapping ?: [];
    $offset = $this->offset_rows;
    while ( ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $deliminator)) !== FALSE )
    {
        // Offset the specified number of rows
        while ( $offset > 0 )
        {
            //If the row being read is the first,
            //store the CSV header names in the array
            $index = 0;
            while ($index < sizeof($row)) {
                array_push($Csv_header_array, $row[$index]);
                $index++;
            }
            $offset--;
            continue 2;
        }
        // No mapping specified - grab the first CSV row and use it
        if ( !$mapping )
        {
            $mapping = $row;
        }
        else
        {
            // Array to store a map of CSV column headers
            // to the corresponding values
            $source_array = $this->readRow($row, $Csv_header_array);
            // Create a map of database column names to
            // the corresponding values
            $row = $this->fillMapArray($source_array, $mapping);
            // insert only non-empty rows from the csv file
            if ( !$row )
                continue;
            $data[$row_count] = $row;
            // Chunk size reached, insert
            if ( ++$row_count == $this->insert_chunk_size )
            {
                //var_dump($this->insert($data));
                $this->insert($data);
                $row_count = 0;
                //var_dump($data[0]);
                // clear the data array explicitly to
                // avoid duplicate inserts
                $data = array();
            }
        }
    }
    // Insert any leftover rows
    if ( count($data)  )
        $this->insert($data);
    fclose($handle);
    return $data;
}
public function readRow( array $row, array $Csv_header_array )
{
    // Read the values of CSV column headers and map them
    // into an array
    $source_array = [];
    foreach ($Csv_header_array as $index => $csvCol) {
        if (!isset($row[$index]) || $row[$index] === '') {
            $source_array[$csvCol] = NULL;
        }
        else {
            $source_array[$csvCol] = $row[$index];
        }
    }
    return $source_array;
}
public function fillMapArray($source_array, $mapping) {
    $row_values = [];
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('maps');
    $no_of_columns_to_fill = sizeof($source_array);
    // Retrieve the CSV column header corresponding to
    // the Database column and store in a map
    foreach($mapping as $dbCol) {
        if ($dbCol === 'year') {
            $row_values[$dbCol] = 2014;
        } else {
            if ($dbCol === 'School_ID') {
                $temp1 = DB::Table('schools')->where('Unit_Id', '=',
                    $source_array['UNITID'])->value('School_ID');
                $row_values[$dbCol] = $temp1;
            } else {
                if ($no_of_columns_to_fill > 0) {
                    $csv_Column_name = DB::Table('maps')->where($columns[3], '=', $this->table)
                        ->where($columns[1], $dbCol)->value($columns[2]);
                    if ($csv_Column_name === Null) {
                        $no_of_columns_to_fill--;
                    } else {
                        $row_values[$dbCol] = $source_array[$csv_Column_name];
                        $no_of_columns_to_fill--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //var_dump($row_values);
    return $row_values;
}
public function insert( array $seedData )
{
    try {
        DB::table($this->table)->insert($seedData);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error("CSV insert failed: " . $e->getMessage() . " - CSV " . $this->filename);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maatwebsite Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package to get the CSV data  then map it to Eloquent model. Example if your CSV table is `users` then your model will be `User`

So you can extract all the data from CSV and then map it to model.

```
// This array will be created with the help of Laravel-Excel package
$users = array(
    array('name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096'),
    array('name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048'),
    //...
);

// your second CSV file will also perform similar task and map it to same array
$users[] = ['name' => 'Coder 3'];

// Start bulk insert
User::insert($users);
```